# What are the possible reasons why my subclass QTableWiget do not display?

Tags: qt

I subclass a QTableWidget class and wanted to display in QTabWidget, something like this:

```
class Mainwindow:
_tabWidget->addTab(doc, QFileInfo(doc->fileName()).fileName());
class doc:
_tableWidget = new QTableWidget(row, column);
```

I can debug that "doc" is not NULL.
_tableWidget have values in rows and cells.
But all I can see on my application is the display of tab with correct label,
there are no rows and columns drawn.
I created the _tabWidget programmatically.
What are the reasons why the content of "doc" were not displayed?
Thanks in advance.

I tried to access the QTableWidget object of custom class from the Mainwindow class using a getter function (doc->table()):

```
_tabWidget->addTab(doc->table(), QFileInfo(doc->fileName()).fileName());
```

The rows and columns are now displayed.
Is it really the way to do it?

Comment: `doc` may be invisible

Comment: @Dmitry Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Can you show more code? Your's not informative at all.

Comment: @someoneinthebox Sorry I am not really sure what to put. All I deed was to create a subclass with QTableWidget in the constructor.  I used that class to load in tab widget which is in the main class.

Comment: Just edit your post and put there your full code of `MainWindow` and `Doc` classes.

Comment: @someoneinthebox I updated the post to reflect some information. The QTableWidget has data, it just don't display. Codes contains thousands of lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing in the little piece of code showing is creating a QTabWidget and adding a tab with a QWidget (base class of Doc) object. In your edit (that works), you are no longer adding the QWidget (doc), but adding a QTableWidget object (doc->table()) directly, which works.

I thus can only conclude that you are not setting a layout for QWidget and thus not putting the QTableWidget in the layout.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. But how do I put the base class of DOC in layout? What I did was I put the tabWidget in layout but no effect at all.